# Filter range in a formula

Tags: excel

Is it possible to filter a range in a formula ? 
E.g., I have cells with data validations (dropdowns). Data validation refers to named ranges. Named ranges are based on 'tables'.
First dropdown is product. If first dropdown has selected a value (e.g., wheels), the second dropdown (dimensions [of wheels]) should show only wheel dimensions and not all dimensions of all products.
(Of course, my dimension table has also the column product.

I'd like to filter a named range in the formula so I can set it in the data validations. Ideally, I don't want to use macros.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can achieve this with helper table. For each additional hierarchy you will need to add additional helper table. So for instance if have first drop down in cell `G1`, and helper table in columns `A:B`, select cell `H1`, set data validation ==> list, and in formula part enter this formula `=OFFSET(B2,MATCH($G$1,$A$2:$A$3000,0)-1,0,COUNTIF($A$2:$A$3000,$G$1),1)`
[image]

Now drop down in cell `H1` id dependent on drop down in cell `G1`.

[image]